# Airflow: Prevent scheduler from triggering DAG, as long as DAG still running

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there a possibility to prevent the scheduler from triggering a DAG as long as there is still a running instance from the same DAG?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in the Docs. Passing the flag `max_active_runs` while constructing the `DAG` object, does the trick:

```
DAG(max_active_runs=1)
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html