# Stopping the next execution of an Airflow DAG while the current execution is still running

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are running Airflow on Google Cloud Composer (GCC) and we have a very long running task currently live that we want to finish. However, the schedule for the DAG is frequent enough that the next execution will start before this current one is finished.

**If we pause the DAG to stop its next scheduled execution, will this also cause the current run to fail?**

The end of [these docs](https://www.restack.io/docs/airflow-faq-deprecated-rest-api-ref-02) suggests that we are able to do this.

Unfortunately, we can't edit the code as the run is currently live, so the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192307/airflow-prevent-scheduler-from-triggering-dag-as-long-as-dag-still-running) is not possible.

Comment: Good question! Perhaps you could manually fail the task from the next execution as soon as it gets queued to avoid having multiple instances simultaneously.

Comment: Yep we thought of doing that however a number of our scheduled executions trigger in the middle of the night! But, if you see my answer below, our suggestion is possible and pausing a DAG will stop any new executions from triggering whilst the current one finishes executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look at the [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#dag-pausing-deactivation-and-deletion) themselves:

> When a DAG is paused, **any running tasks are allowed to complete** and all downstream tasks are put in to a state of “Scheduled”. When the DAG is unpaused, any “scheduled” tasks will begin running according to the DAG logic. DAGs with no “scheduled” tasks will begin running according to their schedule.

So it is possible to pause a DAG to stop any new scheduled executions from running while waiting for the current execution to finish.

However, something to note, is that the **task** will finish not the entire DAG. So any follow up tasks to the task in question will be paused until the whole DAG is unpaused.

Answer (score 1):

If you can just set the 'schedule_interval' parameter to 'None', you will prevent the next run. This does not change the running dag.

Comment: This would be ideal for us, however, as mentioned in the original question, we can't edit the code as the DAG is currently running live

Comment: You can't edit because there are some other ci/cd-like processes and these will break the current dag run or do you just think editing running dag will break something? I have made changes like this many times in the running dag and there was no problem. It will only prevent the next dag run.

Comment: We were afraid that updating the script and deploying would affect the current run. However, is this not the case?

Comment: If you just edit the 'schedule_interval' to 'None', then nothing will change in the current run. But not every change is like this. If you change something inside the tasks or the dependency between tasks, it will affect the current run for example.